# Alternative for executing php function, iframe inside JavaScript Alert()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been wondering if there is an alternative for the javascript Alert() (as it doesn't allow anything but text to be runned inside it) from it's bootstrap meaning no jQuery UI Dialog, or jQuery in general as an example.

### Example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("<iframe src="url"></iframe>")
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("<?php echo $function;?>")
</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: I'd like an alternative for the alert() that allows iframes and such to be runned inside it, using a function from the javascript bootsrap.

Answer (score 0):

For dialogs specifically you have 3 options:

`alert()` - Static message to the user with "OK" button

`confirm()` - Yes/No question that will return as `true` or `false`

`prompt()` - Returns whatever string the user types in

I also understand you're looking for something prettier and more useful but without jQuery or your own Javascript / CSS combo, there's not much you can do.

[Reference for you](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)